# SOAP Send Error on deployment - System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, app-config

I have developed a c# class library that communicates with a web service via WCF.  A service reference was added from the WSDL.  This was manipulated to facilitate the use of X509 certificates for signing the request.

An extremely simple test app that utilises the DLL works perfectly on my development machine.

However when deploying the test app to a new machine, the following response is returned:

> SOAP Send Error
>
> The operation 'inquirePreAuthorizationAsync' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

I'm thinking this is a misleading message - due to the fact that it is working fine on the dev machine - and surely if there was an issue then it would occur on both machines?

Any help to work out what is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else experiences the same issue - it turned out to be a .net issue.
Had customer re-install .net framework, and everything started working.
Cheers
Darren